# Could someone provide Android Native's AAudio (Android O) example of the write function?

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk

Since Android O and AAudio is relatively new, there is not much documentation or examples out there, apart from the Android NDK API (which is not really as good as the Android SDK API), and the googlesamples example of AAudio. I have been looking at google's example, but there is this AAudioStream_write() function that I want to use but they didn't give any example of it.

Have somebody used this write function before, and could give an example on how to use it with sinewave or file (ex. .wav)? Currently I have just created a stream, but I need the data to output sound. I have done this in the Java layer with AudioTrack, but it is not really the same as the native one.

Answer (score 1):

The write() in AAudio is a blocking I/O function. That means that you can just write the data and it will return when the data has been consumed.

If you create an AAudio stream without specifying a callback function then AAudio will expect you to read() or write() the stream.

You should probably create a thread that is dedicated to generating the audio data and writing to the stream.  The basic flow is:

```
timeout = 1000000000; // one second, for example
open_stream
while(result >= 0 && whatever) {
    generate_audio_data()
    result = AAudioStream_write(stream, data, numFrames, timeout)
}
close_stream
```

The generate_audio_data() function could be a synthesizer or it could read from a file, etc.

The callback is recommended for a synthesizer because the callback thread has high priority and synthesizers tend to have predictable performance.
If you are streaming from a network or from a file then blocking read/write() is probably better. Be sure to make your buffers big enough to cover network delays. Otherwise you will get an audio glitch from underflows.

More information is here:
https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/audio/aaudio/aaudio#reading-writing-streams